# Why is this Spring Batch Bean not auto wired in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-batch

I'm not sure why my `delegate` bean is not being wired and is null.  Can any one offer any advice please?

Within ScheduleJobBatchConfig.groovy:

```
beans {
    xmlns batch:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"

    batch.job(id: 'scheduleJob', restartable: true) {
        batch.step(id: 'scheduleStep1') {
            batch.tasklet {
                batch.chunk(
                        reader: 'scheduleReaderWrapper',
                        writer: 'scheduleWriter',
                        'commit-interval': 50
                )
            }
        }
    }

    scheduleReaderWrapper(ScheduleReaderWrapper) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = 'byName'
        delegate = ref('basicScheduleReader')  // this is null
    }

    basicScheduleReader(FlatFileItemReader) { bean ->
        bean.scope = 'step'
        resource = "#{jobParameters['file']}"
        lineMapper = ref('scheduleLineMapper')
    }

    // more sub-beans here
}
```

This is the bean that isn't being wired (within src/groovy):

```
public class ScheduleReaderWrapper implements ItemStreamReader<Object> {

    private ItemStreamReader<Object> delegate;

    public Object read() throws Exception {
        // do some reading here
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setDelegate(ItemStreamReader<Object> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.close();
    }

    public void open(ExecutionContext arg0) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.open(arg0);
    }

    public void update(ExecutionContext arg0) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update(arg0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Closures have a settable `delegate` property via the `setDelegate` and `getDelegate` methods. This is often used when implementing DSLs.

This code is invoked as a method call to register the bean definition:

```
scheduleReaderWrapper(ScheduleReaderWrapper) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
    delegate = ref('basicScheduleReader')
}
```

It's basically the same as `void beanName(Class c, Closure c) { ... }` and its using the ability in Groovy to leave the closure outside of the method args. There's obviously no `scheduleReaderWrapper` method, but the DSL delegate (the bean builder) handles the missing method exception and uses the method name as the bean name, and since the first arg is a Class it uses that as the bean class, and the optional second arg is a Closure, so that's invoked to customize the bean properties.

The bean builder relies on calling non-existent methods and getting and setting non-existent properties, so it is notified of those calls and can use the method/property names and args to configure the bean.

This

```
delegate = ref('basicScheduleReader')
```

is the equivalent of

```
setDelegate(ref('basicScheduleReader'))
```

but it's invoked inside a closure, which has a `setDelegate` method. If it used any other property name that doesn't exist in the Closure class it would trigger a missing property exception, and be interpreted as a call to set that property on the `ScheduleReaderWrapper` instance while it's being configured by Spring.

For example if you change the property in `ScheduleReaderWrapper` to `wrappedReader` it will work as expected:

```
wrappedReader = ref('basicScheduleReader')
```

Comment: That's a very nice answer, thank you very much.  For reference, in case anyone else comes across this page, I was following the example in "Pro Spring Batch" on page 191 for dealing with multi-line records.  It uses a `delegate` variable (but of course, by using raw Spring and not using Grails, it doesn't result in this problem).